# Send instance method to module

Tags: ruby, module, send

Given the following module,

```
module Foo
  def bar
    :baz
  end
end

def send_to_foo(method)
  # ...?
end

send_to_foo(:bar) # => :baz
```

What code should go in `send_to_foo` to make the last line work as expected? (`send_to_foo` is obviously not how I would implement this; it just makes clearer what I'm looking for.)

I expected `Foo.send(:bar)` to work at first, but it makes sense that it doesn't. It would if the method were defined as `def self.bar`, but that's no fun.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well, the easy way would be

```
Foo.extend Foo # let Foo use the methods it contains as instance methods
def send_to_foo(method)
  Foo.send(method)
end
```

So now

```
irb> send_to_foo(:bar)
 #=> :baz
```